# Localized short time string using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

How do I get time string from moment.js object with respect to current locale?

```
moment().format('HH:mm')
```

always get the same result regardless of localization.

I want similar result as I would use in angular using shortTime:

```
formatDate(new Date(), 'shortTime'): // HH:mm, resp hh:mm a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use **Localized formats** listed in [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs

> Because preferred formatting differs based on locale, there are a few tokens that can be used to format a moment based on its locale.
>
> There are upper and lower case variations on the same formats. The lowercase version is intended to be the shortened version of its uppercase counterpart.

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment().format('LT') );
moment.locale('it');
console.log( moment().format('LT') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you know how to change "8:39 PM" to "8:39pm"?

Comment: @Julia if you need to get "8:39pm" you can use "`HH:mm a`" as formatting token.

Comment: Yep, but I need to use “LT” for localization)

Comment: @Julia if you want to customized the output of `LT`, you can use [`updateLocale`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/) function, so you can have something like: `moment.updateLocale('en', {longDateFormat : { LT: "HH:mm a"} })`. Please consider searching other question similar to yours on SO or ask a new one, instead of asking for custom cases in the comments.